# Has Number Fields by D. Marcus ever been typeset using TeX by anyone yet?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, reference-works

As the title suggests, has anyone yet "latexed" Number Fields by Marcus yet? It's a classic book on number theory and I was thinking of slowly typesetting it in LaTeX during my free time, if no one has done it yet.

Are there any copyright ramifications (no pun intended :)) due to this? I don't intend to make any money from this.

Comment: The contents of the book is most probably protected by copyright. You can't just reformat it and make it freely available. See page 2 in https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4684-9356-6%2F1.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I figured it would be something like that.

Comment: Hey, I actually like that book a lot as well and I think it should be TeXed. I could help you if you want.

Comment: @1717 Have you finished the typing works? I am willing to join you. But it seems there is a new version they are going to publish. 
https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319902326 in Sep. 2018.

Comment: @bfhaha I think since they're about to publish a new version, it's best if we don't type anything up. They are clearly still trying to make money out of it. It'd be a nice book to have once it gets typed up.

Comment: Update: Yes , a new version of this book has now been published by Springer typesetted in LaTeX by Emanuele Sacco this year.